# Is UiPath Orchestrator mandatory to create and deploy a UiPath Robot on localhost?

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-robot, uipath-orchestrator

I have been working with [UiPath Studio](https://studio.uipath.com/) to automate workflows and was successful. Now I want to create a [**UiPath Robot**](https://robot.uipath.com/) to deploy only on my **localhost**.

I have followed a couple of videos, e.g. [UiPath Tutorials For Beginners - Deploying a bot to Orchestrator || Schedule a bot Uipath](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o6P7wz80LwI) which seems to take help of the [UiPath Orchestrator](https://orchestrator.uipath.com/).

My questions are:

- Is it absolutely necessary to use *UiPath Orchestrator* to create and deploy a UiPath Robot on on my *localhost*?
- If it is mandatory, is there any UiPath official videos available?
- If it is not mandatory, can you please point me to some documentation/videos?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

regarding your questions:

- Is it absolutely necessary to use UiPath Orchestrator to create and
  deploy a UiPath Robot on on my localhost?

No it is not necessary. Community edition of UiPath, already includes your first robot. Whenever you execute/run your workflows this robot is activated and takes action. Connecting your robot to the Orchectrator though provides you with the following benefits:

1. a centralized location from which to deploy automation projects to Robots
2. an easier and centralized point for the management and monitoring of multiple Robots
3. the scheduled execution of automation processes on Robots
4. centralized Robot logging to SQL and/or ElasticSearch

You can check your robot on the bottom right corner it has the same icon as UiPath logo.

- If it is mandatory, is there any UiPath official videos available?

I would suggest you to enroll to UiPath Academy and check Level 2 Orchestrator Training. It is very detailed and covers all aspects about the benefits mentioned in your first question.

- If it is not mandatory, can you please point me to some
  documentation/videos?

About setting up a robot locally without Orchestrator please check [Installing the Robot](https://robot.uipath.com/docs/installing-the-robot)

There are three steps to follow in order to execute your workflow without Orchestrator locally:

1. Publish your project
   [image]
2. Launch your UiPath Robot either from system tray or search for UiPath Robot under your windows search and launch it. Check under available processes and highlight the one that you want[image]
3. As you highlight/select the process that you want on the right side of the name a start button will appear and you can run it.

[image]

---

Hope these information will help you.